# iOS NSHotSpot and WISPr

Tags: ios, wispr

I'm trying to implement my app to automatically login to our captive network/hotspot (the app already have the cridentials)

When connecting with NEHotspotConfigurationManager (with no credentials) the device says to be connected to the hotspot (in settings and programatically), but when trying to do a WISPr request the request is routed via the Mobile network. If I turn mobile off the request fails. If opening wifi under settings the CNA-browser is opened.
So does anyone have an idea why I don't get a network connection? And is there a workaround to get the app to get a local connection. (It will of course not be able to communicate to WAN before the WISPr request has been completed)